# str.replace not working inside html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, replace

I need to replace all `_` from a string in my angular app. In my controller, following code gives correct result:

`alert("this_is_string_".replace(/_/g, " "));`

But when I put the same code in my html file like this:

```
 <th class="text-center" ng-repeat="(key, value) in filteredEL[0] ">
    {{ key.replace(/_/g, ' ') }}
 </th>
```

it gives following error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '/' not a primary expression at column 13 of the expression [key.replace(/_/g, ' ')] starting at [/_/g, ' ')]
```

So, how can I use replace function that replaces all required instances inside the html?

Comment: `{{ key.replace(/_/g, ' ') }}` is considered as angular expression.

Comment: i know. Funny thing is `{{ key.replace('_', ' ') }}` works fine but it only removes first instance. I need to replace all of them.

Comment: Just to provide more insights on why this doesn't work. The `key.replace(/_/g, ' ')` tries to use a `regular expression` to remove all occurences of that pattern. Here is an extract from the Angular docs `You can't declare functions or create regular expressions from within AngularJS expressions. This is to avoid complex model transformation logic inside templates. Such logic is better placed in a controller or in a dedicated filter where it can be tested properly.`.  Ref: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a dedicated filter :

```
angular.module('filters.stringUtils', [])

.filter('removeUnderscores', [function() {
    return function(string) {
        if (!angular.isString(string)) {
            return string;
        }
        return string.replace(/_/g, '');
    };
}])
```

and call it like :

```
<div id="{{'hi_there'| removeUnderscores}}"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Fadhly Permata and Syam Pillai

Comment: @TahreemIqbal: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 4):

Using angular filter is the best practice to filter from html.

Have a look at **[angular-filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)** here

```js
.filter('customFilter', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return function (input) {
      if (input) {
       return input.replace(/_/g, '');
      }
  }
}])
```

```html
<th class="text-center" ng-repeat="(key, value) in filteredEL[0] ">
    {{ key | customFilter}}
 </th>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use split and join.

```
<th class="text-center" ng-repeat="(key, value) in filteredEL[0] ">
{{ key.split('_').join('') }}</th>
```

Comment: Please elaborate what split and join is. Or just make your answer a bit bigger.